# The location service gets disabled after a while on some apps

Tags: google-chrome, system-settings, big-sur, geolocation

Some apps that I enabled 'allowing location' checkbox on keep disabled after a while. This include Chromium and Chrome Canary but not Chrome.

[image]

After I set 'location service' to on, I always lock the setting by clicking the lock icon on the bottom. But this is very consistent and some apps keep disabled automatically.

Is this designed by the system or dependent on each app? How can I set the location such that it is permanent?

Comment: I have the same problem with Google Chrome on High Sierra.